# Rank of a matrix over $GF(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I realize this is a simple problem, but I'm working through a book and trying to practice the concepts. I have posted a solution in the answers.

**Problem:** Working over the field with two elements, find the rank of the following matrix: 
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 0        \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1           & 1 \\[0.3em]
       1           & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the rank is equal to the dimension of the row space, we consider the span of the following three vectors:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 0           
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 1           
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 1           
\end{bmatrix}.$

Notice that adding the first and second produces the third. It is easy to see that the first and second are linearly independent (one would have the be a multiple of the other, but the only thing we can multiply by in this field is 1 or 0, both of which don't work) so the rank is $2$.

Comment: If anyone knows how to properly align the vectors, please do. I'm still learning how to work with matrices in LaTeX.

Comment: +1 This is one of the better ways of looking at the problem. A coding theorist might say that all the columns have an even number of 1s. IOW they are "orthogonal" to $(1,1,1)^T$, and hence cannot span the entire space. That doesn't tell nearly the whole story, though. It is just a quick trick specific to $GF(2)$. Your approach works more generally.